# Laravel Authorization can Guest

Tags: laravel

I am trying to Authorize Guest to show login form if not logged in.

```
@can('guest')
    <a href="/login">Let's Start</a>
@endcan
```

Where do I need to define guest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the Blade templating engine provides so-called `authentication directives` which determine whether a user is authenticated or not:

```
@auth
    // User is authenticated.
@endauth

@guest
    // User is not authenticated.
@endguest
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from prd is a very good approach and will work in newer laravel version. (Probably from 5.5)

However if you still want to use `can('guest')` format, you can do that.

You need to put your custom blade directive in `AppServiceProvider.php` file and inside `boot` method.

```
Blade::if('can', function ($role) {
            if($role=='guest'){
                 return !(auth()->check());
            }
            // you can also put codes for can('admin') etc 
            // the return value should be true or false.
        });
```

For more information you can read [this](https://laravel-news.com/bladeif).